# How to add or remove a 'minus' sign prefixed in a textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to add or remove a prefixed minus sign from a textfield. The button should act like a toggle.

I wrote a function to check if textfield already has a minus sign. If not add one. If it already has one then remove it.

```
protocol KeyboardDelegate {
    func toggleMinus(_ character: String)
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {


    var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "NumpadView", bundle: nil)
        let objects = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)

        view = objects[0] as! UIView

        // Perform custom UI setup here
    }
       // Toggle minus button action function of custom keyboard
       @IBAction func negateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var string = sender.titleLabel?.text
        self.delegate?.toggleMinus(string!)
    }

}
```

```
class TemperatureViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textCelcius: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFahrenheit: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textKelvin: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textCelcius.delegate = self
        textFahrenheit.delegate = self
        textKelvin.delegate = self
    }

    func toggleMinus(_ character: String) {
        if var text = textCelcius.text , text.isEmpty == false{
            textCelcius.insertText(character)

            if text.hasPrefix("-") {
                text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
            } else {
                text = "-\(text)"
            }

            textCelcius.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

I want the prefix value of a textfield to change to a minus sign or remove it if it already has one when the user presses the button on the custom keyboard. Right now when I press the button on the keyboard nothing happens. I think I haven't called the `toggleMinus()` function in the `TemperatureViewController` properly from the `KeyboardViewController` class or there is a logical error in the `toggleMinus()` function.

Comment: The issue is that you don't set up the `delegate` of `KeyboardViewController` anywhere, so the delegate methods cannot be called. However, without seeing how you present `KeyboardViewController` or where can you access it from, it's hard to write the exact code for fixing it.

Comment: Set a couple breakpoints to make sure your functions are being called. If not, that's what you need to solve. If yes, then step through in the debugger and inspect your variables and code execution.